# How can we decrease code execution time in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have the below code to replace NUL characters in a text file. This code is working as per my requirement for smaller files but the problem is when the file size is increasing it is taking more time. I have a file which consists of more than 200,000 lines consists of 160MB+ size. I have executed my code for this file and I waited for more than 2 hours still the code executing.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TriStateUseDefault = -2

If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 0) Then
  sInfile = WScript.Arguments(0)
Else
  WScript.Echo "No filename specified."
  WScript.Quit
End If
If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 1) Then
  sOutfile = WScript.Arguments(1)
Else
  sOutfile = sInfile
End If

'Get the text file from cmd file
sData = ""
FinalData = ""
sInfile = WScript.Arguments(1)
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\x00.*"
re.Global  = True
Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile, 1, False, -1)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  sData = Replace(f.ReadLine, vbCrLf, "")
  FinalData = FinalData + re.Replace(sData, "") + vbCrLf
Loop
f.Close
Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, 2, True, -1)
oOutfile.Write(FinalData)
oOutfile.Close
Set oOutfile = Nothing
Set oFS = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Is there any way to optimize the code to execute in less interval of time.

**EDIT 1:**
Updated Code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TriStateUseDefault = -2

If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 0) Then
  sInfile = WScript.Arguments(0)
Else
  WScript.Echo "No filename specified."
  WScript.Quit
End If
If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 1) Then
  sOutfile = WScript.Arguments(1)
Else
  sOutfile = sInfile
End If

'Get the text file from cmd file
sData = ""
FinalData = ""
sInfile = WScript.Arguments(1)
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\x00.*"
re.Global  = True
Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile, 1, False, -1)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  sData = Replace(f.ReadAll, vbCrLf, "")
  FinalData = FinalData + re.Replace(sData, "") + vbCrLf
Loop 
f.Close
Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, 2, True, -1)
oOutfile.Write(FinalData)
oOutfile.Close
Set oOutfile = Nothing
Set oFS = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: It is Vb script

Comment: Concatenating two strings takes a lot of time. Don't do FinalData = FinalData + ....

Writing as you read will be much faster.

Also, doing a simple Replace will be faster than a RegEx Replace.

Comment: @RegisDesrosiers the pattern which I am trying to find out is regular expression (From start of NUL character to end of line). I can't exclude RegEx here

Comment: Using `ReadAll` for large files is not recommended, because it might exhaust the available RAM, causing the system to come grinding to a halt.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `ReadAll` for large files. Reading large files into memory might exhaust the available RAM on your computer, so that it will come grinding to a halt because it starts swapping.

Also avoid concatenating strings in a loop, because the operation is slow.

Change this:

```
Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile, 1, False, -1)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  sData = Replace(f.ReadLine, vbCrLf, "")
  FinalData = FinalData + re.Replace(sData, "") + vbCrLf
Loop
f.Close
Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, 2, True, -1)
oOutfile.Write(FinalData)
oOutfile.Close
```

to this:

```
Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile, 1, False, -1)
Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, 2, True, -1)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  oOutFile.WriteLine re.Replace(f.ReadLine, "")
Loop
f.Close
oOutfile.Close
```

Same code with string operations instead of a regular expression replacement:

```
Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile, 1, False, -1)
Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, 2, True, -1)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = f.ReadLine
  pos = InStr(line, Chr(0))
  If pos > 0 Then line = Left(line, pos-1)
  oOutFile.WriteLine line
Loop
f.Close
oOutfile.Close
```

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar I tried both methods still it is taking more time (I started execution and waited for more than 20 mins still the code is executing) and my disk utilization is also going very high (~98%)

Comment: Can't reproduce. I ran both variants with a 600MB Unicode file in a test VM and each process took ~15min. Please provide evidence.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not up to date, but it might be useful to someone.
I tried another approach that **takes about 5 seconds!** :) 
It seems that scripting engine (wscript) or `FileSystemObject` has a problem loading 160 MB at a time (by `.ReadAll` method).
So I tried to load all data (into the `Dictionary`) line by line via `.ReadLine`, process it and then save it to the output file at once.

Appendix:
 - I added the option to create a test file - if you specify "CreateData" as the second argument:
`wscript util.vbs "C:\Temp\SampleData.txt" CreateData`
 - You do not need to remove CR + LF from a string that returns `.ReadLine`. They are already skipped.
 - Sometimes it is good to test `.AtEndOfStream` before `.ReadAll` method, because if the file will be empty, the method will cause run-time error.

```
Dim mode, sInFile, sOutFile

If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 0) Then
    sInfile = WScript.Arguments(0)
Else
  WScript.Echo "No filename specified."
  WScript.Quit
End If

If (WScript.Arguments.Count > 1) Then
  If StrComp(WScript.Arguments(1), "CreateData", 1) = 0 then
    mode = "CreateData"
    sOutfile = sInFile
  Else
    mode = "processing"
    sOutfile = WScript.Arguments(1)
  End If
Else
  mode = "processing"
  sOutfile = sInfile
End If

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if mode = "CreateData" then
  Call CreateDataFile(sInfile, 160) '160 = approx. 160 MB'
  Wscript.Quit
end if

Dim dictData, i, sLine, tim
tim = Timer()

'Load data
set dictData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInfile, 1, False, -1)
do while not f.AtEndOfStream
  dictData.Add dictData.Count, f.ReadLine()
loop
f.Close

'Process data
for each i in dictData
  sLine = dictData(i)
  dictData(i) = Replace(sLine, Chr(0), "")
next

'Save processed data
sFinalData = Join(dictData.Items, vbCrLf)
Set oOutfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sOutfile, 2, True, -1)
oOutFile.Write sFinalData
oOutfile.Close

'Message
WScript.Echo "Data processed (" & (Timer() - tim) & " sec)"

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub CreateDataFile(ByVal sFilePath, ByVal nSizeInMB)
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Dim sLine, arrData, i, iMax, sData, tim
  rem tim = Timer()
  sLine = String(255, "A") & Chr(0) & String(254, "B")
  iMax = CLng((nSizeInMB*1024*1024)/(Len(sLine)*2)) 'Unicode chars take 2 bytes

  ReDim arrData(iMax)
  for i = 0 to iMax
    arrData(i) = sLine
  next
  sData = Join(arrData, vbCrLf)

  set oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(sFilePath, True, True)
  oFile.Write sData
  oFile.Close
  rem WScript.Echo "Data created (" & (Timer() - tim) & " sec)"
end sub
```